# Django-simple-history how to append extra info/object to historical record?

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

I'm looking for a way to change extra field in historical record.

I have a model `Invoice` and `Balance`.

```
class UserBalanceHistoricalModel(models.Model):

    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                verbose_name='Faktúra')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class UserBalance(TimeStampedModel):
    objects = UserBalanceManager()
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='user_balance', verbose_name='Užívateľ')
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0, verbose_name="Eur na konte")
    history = HistoricalRecords(bases=[UserBalanceHistoricalModel, ])

class Invoice(models.Model):
    ...
```

Everytime when `Invoice` object is created, the `UserBalance.balance` is modified and historical record is automatically created.

I want to add this `Invoice` object to the historical record but it doesn't work. The `invoice_id` is `None`.

```
In [10]: u = User.objects.first()

In [11]: i = Invoice.objects.first()

In [12]: balance = u.user_balance

In [13]: balance.balance = 45 

In [16]: balance.history.invoice = i

In [18]: balance.save()

In [28]: balance.history.all().values_list('invoice_id',flat=True)
Out[28]: <QuerySet [None, None, None, None]>
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`balance.history` is accessing the `HistoryManager` class of balance, which is essentially a manager for the history model rather than a history model instance itself. Thus, the line `balance.history.invoice = i` is just setting a local variable on the manager class, which doesn't have any effect. The actual history model instance isn't created until balance is saved with `balance.save()`. What you want to do is access the `pre_create_historical_record` signal, which is sent after the `balance` is saved, but before the historical instance is saved. This is documented [here](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.0/advanced.html#adding-additional-fields-to-historical-models).

For your use case, you can setup a receiver for the `pre_create_historical_record` signal that takes the `history_instance` and edits the `invoice` field with whatever value you'd like. You could pass invoice on the base object and then delete it like so:

```
# in apps.py
def add_invoice_to_historical_balance(sender, instance, historical_instance, **kwargs):
    historical_instance.invoice = instance.invoice
    del instance.invoice

class BalanceConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        from ..models import HistoricalUserBalance

        pre_create_historical_record.connect(
             add_invoice_to_historical_balance,
             sender=HistoricalUserBalance,
             dispatch_uid='add_invoice_to_historical_balance'
        )
```

Your code above would look like this:

```
In [10]: u = User.objects.first()

In [11]: i = Invoice.objects.first()

In [12]: balance = u.user_balance

In [13]: balance.balance = 45 

In [16]: balance.invoice = i

In [18]: balance.save()
```